# Express Query string multiple parameters error?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, backend

I have a router which works when two of the query parameters are inserted .
This URL happens to work - http://localhost:3000/country/?category=phone&subcategory=oppo ]
wheras single paramter does not work -http://localhost:3000/country/?category=phone

```
router.get('/:category?/:subcategory?', async (req, res) =>{
    try {
        const category = req.query.category
        const subcategory = req.query.subcategory
        
        const data = await Model.find({category: category,subcategory: subcategory});
        res.json(data)
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: error.message })
    }
})
```

I was hoping for  /?category=phones to display phones and  /?category=phones&subcategory=iphones to both display the correct information

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to enter a separate :something in the route to access the query.

```
router.get('/country', async (req, res) =>{
    try {
        const category = req.query.category
        const subcategory = req.query.subcategory
        
        const data = await Model.find({category: category,subcategory: subcategory});
        res.json(data)
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: error.message })
    }
})
```

This should work, please check your output.

Comment: https://stackabuse.com/get-query-strings-and-parameters-in-express-js/

Comment: This gives me the same output as before . It returns an empty array when only the first query is inputted but only gives correct output when both queries are put in

Comment: Can you provide sample data?

Comment: name :"iphone12" , category = "phone" , subcategory = "iphone" .

Comment: http://localhost:3000/country/?category=phone&subcategory=iphone works but http://localhost:3000/country/?category=phone does not